# Why Truecaller SDK gives me an error: 40304, Invalid fingerprint in my flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, sha1, fingerprint

I am trying to integrate Truecaller SDK into my flutter app. I am using truecaller_sdk flutter package. I followed everything that is mentioned in the Truecaller developer docs. I got the client ID using the package name and SHA-1 fingerprint. I have entered the fingerprint correctly and I can ensure that because I have the same fingerprint in the firebase too and the firebase works as intended.

I am getting the error code: 40304 and error message: Invalid fingerprint

I don't understand what is invalid or what I am doing wrong.